# find-or-create idiom in REST API design?

Tags: rest, api-design

say we have a 'user' resource with unique constraint on 'name'. how would you design a REST API to handle a find-or-create (by name) use case? I see the following options:

### option 1: multiple requests

client:

```
POST /user
{"name":"bob"}
```

server:

```
HTTP 409 //or something else
```

client:

```
GET /user?name=bob
```

server:

```
HTTP 200 //returns existing user
```

### option 2: one request, two response codes

client:

```
POST /user
{"name":"bob"}
```

server:

```
HTTP 200 //returns existing user
```

(in case user is actually created, return HTTP 201 instead)

### option 3: request errs but response data contains conflicting entity

client:

```
POST /user
{"name":"bob"}
```

server:

```
HTTP 409 //as in option1, since no CREATE took place
{"id": 1, "name":"bob"} //existing user returned
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the "correct" RESTful way to do this would be :

```
GET /user?name=bob
   200: entity contains user
   404: entity does not exist, so
        POST /user { "name" : "bob" }
           303: GET /user?name=bob
                200: entity contains user
```

I'm also a big fan of the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, which would entail the server sending a redirect to the client with the uri of the newly created user. Your response in the POST case would then have the entity in its body with a status code of 200.

This does mean either 1 or 3 round-trips to the server.  The big advantage of PRG is protecting the client from rePOSTing when a page reload occurs, but you should read more about it to decide if it's right for you.

If this is too much back-and-forth with the server, you can do option 2. This is not strictly RESTful by my reading of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5:

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource
> that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204
> (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether
> or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.

If you're okay with veering away from the standard, and you're concerned about round-trips, then Option 2 is reasonable.

Comment: very helpful, @Eric Stein. clarification - in the above approach what happens when another process creates 'bob' after the initial GET but before the POST? ie what's the response to POST in that case - a 200 with (now) existing user in body?

Comment: @Nikita In that case, I would expect the POST to return a 403. 409 is no good according to the spec: "This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request." Note that there's a lot of arguing about the proper response code in this situation, so you should Google for a more detailed understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Option 2 for two reasons:

First, HTTP response code, 2xx (e.g. 200 nd 201) refers to a successful operation unlike 4xx. So in both cases when find or create occurs you have a successful operation.

Second, Option 1 doubles the number of requests to the server which can be a performance hit for heavy load.

Comment: that option is indeed less chatty. however, what if we had another use-case - user creation. in that case we would not want to silently return an existing record when attempting to create a new one. If we go with option 2 here, does that mean that another endpoint will be needed (won't that break REST's conventions?); or will client have to interpret HTTP 200 (vs 201) as error in the register-user case?

Comment: @Nikita if you choose option 2, then yes, the client will need to look at the response status to determine whether or not the user was created.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a version of **option 2**. I return 201 when the resource is created, and [303 ("see other")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) when it is merely retrieved. I chose to do this, in part, because get_or_create doesn't seem to be a common REST idiom, and 303 is a slightly unusual response code.

Comment: But POST is not idempotent.
https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/

Answer (score 0):

I believe a GET request which either:

- returns an existing record; or
- creates a new record and returns it

is the most efficient approach as discussed in my answer here: [Creating user record / profile for first time sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033237/creating-user-record-profile-for-first-time-sign-in/55055063#55055063)

It is irrelevant that the server needs to create the record before returning it in the response as explained by @Cormac Mulhall and @Blake Mitchell in [REST Lazy Reference Create GET or POST?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/326183/rest-lazy-reference-create-get-or-post)

This is also explained in [Section 9.1.1 of the HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.1):

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. **The important distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects**, so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Comment: RFC2616 is obsolete. Don't use it. Here is a reference: https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead